# Does Phase Bolt allow Spellstrike to reduce the target's circumstance bonus to AC?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, magus

My [Magus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=17) takes [Phase Bolt](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1159) as a cantrip. They use it with [Spellstrike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=755). My target has Raised a Shield for a +2 circumstance bonus to their AC. Do I Spellstrike against their AC with or without their circumstance bonus? Phase Bolt normally allows me to ignore it, but I'm not positive on how it interacts with Spellstrike. The key phrase in Phase Bolt:

> Make a ranged spell attack roll against your target's AC; if the target has any circumstance bonuses to AC (such as from a shield or cover), reduce that bonus by 2 for this attack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No, you don't gain that (or any other similar spells') benefit

You are not using the spell to attack. [Spellstrike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=755) is pretty clear...

> You channel a spell into a punch or sword thrust to deliver a combined attack. You Cast a Spell that takes 1 or 2 actions to cast and requires a spell attack roll. **The effects of the spell don't occur immediately**¹ but are imbued into your attack instead. **Make a melee Strike with a weapon or unarmed attack.** ² Your spell is coupled with your attack, using your attack roll result to determine the effects of both the Strike and the spell.³

1. The effects of the spell do not occur as they normally would.
2. You are making a *melee* [Strike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=89), which is a type of basic action. Nothing about "the effects" of the spell being "imbued into your attack" alters how you make the Strike.
3. Your (melee) attack roll is used to *determine* the effect of your spell.*

- *Arguably*, you could partially benefit from *phase bolt* and similar effect but *not* for the Strike; you could theoretically miss the target's shielded AC but have *phase bolt* function as it's success condition by hitting their reduced AC because you use the "roll", not the "result" of your Strike.

Comment: This would apply to something like Shocking Grasp as well, yeah? At least RAW, it doesn't grant the +1 circumstance bonus to the Spellstrike attack roll?

Comment: Correct, you would not get the bonus from shocking grasp. Again, arguably, if you miss their AC by one your Strike could miss but shocking grasp could succeed, but I don't feel like that's the intent (nor how I would run my table for simplicity)

Comment: Looking into it, I think this is the RAW reading - I'm not sure I'd run it this way at my table, but I would do so while consciously going against the rules here.

Comment: "... but are imbued into your attack instead." seems like a critical part of that sentence half-bolded. The effect of reduced target AC imbued into your attack seems like it might indeed alter the Strike.

Comment: @brandon the problem I see with that is that it's still part of "don't occur immediately". That leads me to the interpretation that the imbued spell is still delayed until the attack hits. I do expect some table variation on this rule, but I still struggle to find a reason in the text to use an order of operations that doesn't wait until after the melee attack roll to resolve the entirety of the spell.

Comment: I think I personally would rule that a spell like phase bolt or shocking grasp can hit even if the melee attack just barely misses. That's how I always did it in 1e with e.g. draconic sorcerers holding a touch spell to use with a later claw attack, and it worked fine. Ruling that Spellstrike removes phase bolt's special feature reduces the space of reasonable Magus cantrip choices, because it makes phase bolt just strictly worse than telekinetic projectile. Phase bolt is already kind of bad, so I see no reason to weaken it further.

Comment: @ESCE My point is that there's no other mention of when the delay ends, only the rest of the sentence which describes it happening as part of the attack rather than after the attack hits.

Comment: For me, it comes down to the fact that Spellstrike never references making your spell attack, which is what *phase bolt* alters and *shocking grasp* adds to. You make a *melee* Strike that is also used for your spell's effect. Nothing in Spellstrike specifies that the spell affects your *melee* Strike (the default being that they don't) so there is not specific rule to override the general rule that spells do what they say. I agree it *could* be read the other way but think that is a significant stretch (but not unfair if your table wants that to be the rule).

Answer (score 3):

## Strike and Spell as One Attack

> You channel a spell into a punch or sword thrust **to deliver a combined attack**.

Spellstrike involves Casting the Spell and making single attack roll for the results of both the Strike and the spell. Normally this spell's effect is coupled with the Strike that is made, though there are some [specific interactions](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=755) with certain effects that work differently.

Splitting up the steps of making a Spellstrike for clarity, you get:

- You Cast a Spell that requires a spell attack roll. The effects of this spell don't occur immediately but are imbued into your attack instead.
- Make a melee Strike. Your spell is coupled with your attack, using your attack roll to determine the effects of both.

Casting a Spell normally requires immediate resolution by rolling a spell attack, but this ability delays the spells effects until you make an attack roll as a melee Strike. The spell is imbued into that Strike, and both are delivered as "a combined attack".

### *Phase Bolt*

> Make a ranged spell attack roll against your target's AC; if the target has any circumstance bonuses to AC (such as from a shield or cover), reduce that bonus by 2 **for this attack**.

With only one attack being made, *Phase bolt's* effect reducing AC would apply to determine the effects of both Strike and spell.

There are other spells with similar effects that would also apply for a Spellstrike with the same reasoning, such as *[shocking grasp](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=283)* that gives a +1 circumstance bonus on the attack roll if the target is made of metal or wearing metal armor.

### Spellstrike Specifics

There are those specific interactions described for certain types of effects used as part of a Spellstrike that could change how this works, but none of these apply here.

The closest in Ancillary Effects only covers "non-targeted effects that might affect creatures other than the target, as well as any ongoing effects starting from the moment you hit with the Strike", but *phase bolt's* effect to reduce the bonus to a target's AC applies only for that single attack and only to the target.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, my only hesitation is the Ancillary Effects clause in Spellstrike Specifics seems to exclude "pre-hit" effects (like Shocking Grasp's +1 or Phase Bolt here). I'm guessing I'm missing something since Shocking Grasp + Spellstrike is a common combo? What am I missing?

Comment: Ancillary effects actually pretty clearly and explicitly talks about *post-hit* effects such as splash damage, subsequent attacks, etc. it doesn’t have anything to say about Shocking Grasp.

Comment: I think this is how I would run it at my table (I don't think it's overpowered, but I could be wrong). However, I do what the rules *say* aligns more with Ifusaso's answer.

Comment: @brandon I really appreciate you updating your answer to address my concerns - I still lean the other way for the RAW ruling, but this is still a solid case for your interpretation, and I can see tables agreeing to this as RAW. If I could upvote it again I would!